# Mongod server exits on run

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongodb from months now, it worked fine till yesterday but today I am facing trouble. I have 23.7GB free space in the drive where `data\db` path is specified yet it says `Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal`. Is it a bug or something?

```
C:\Users\sadaf2605\Downloads\Compressed\Console2>mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=7020 port=27017 dbpath=\data\db\ 64-bit host=Sadaf
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] git version: d1b43b61a5308c4ad0679d34b262c5af9d664267
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, pla
tform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten]
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal or use --smallfiles
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten]
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 dbexit:
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sun Feb 24 03:20:05 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I have also tried using --smallfiles, yet it does not work!

```
C:\Users\sadaf2605\Downloads\Compressed\Console2>mongod --smallfiles
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6844 port=27017 dbpath=\data\db\ 64-bit host=Sadaf
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.2, pdfile version 4.5
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] git version: d1b43b61a5308c4ad0679d34b262c5af9d664267
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack=
'Service Pack 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] options: { smallfiles: true }
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/networ
k address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] now exiting
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 dbexit:
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] closing listening socket: 464
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sun Feb 24 03:23:38 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Comment: The second error is different from the first? It sounds like MongoDB was already running?

Comment: Double check free space. Also, do you have another drive you could try it on? By default, MongoDB tries to allocate a 3GB journal file upon startup ... [C++ source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/dur_journal.cpp#L322)

Comment: I have tried using it on different drive, used this command `D:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.2.3\bin\mongod.exe`! but no luck!

Comment: Second attempt with --small files failed because it couldn't bind to port 27017 so once you shut down another process using it, you should be fine.

Comment: Different drive means you have to move journal or all of data directory there and then use --dbpath to point mongod at that location.

Comment: Actually currently I don't have any mongod server running! Did you mean if is system is using this port for internal purposes or not? I have tried using different `--ports` but yet it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files

As per above error, free up your space.

See also: [Journal files are present in journal directory, yet starting without journaling enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18044462/55075)

> ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017

This suggest that there is already some process binding on port 27017, which should be killed.